# share button inline keyboard telegram c#

Tags: c#, telegram-bot

i want create share button for share inline keyboard telegram in c#

Who can get help or example code please?

tanx friends

Answer (score 2):

I think you want create share button in telegram by inline keyboard button 
You Should Download telegram library from nuget 
and using SwitchInlineQuery property for create sharebutton

for example :

```
 InlineKeyboardButton[][] inline = new InlineKeyboardButton[][]
        {
                new InlineKeyboardButton[] { new InlineKeyboardButton { Text = "textButton"  , CallbackData = "CalbackData" , SwitchInlineQuery = "forShareText" } }
        };
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't share anything from Telegram directly by the inline keyboard, only link direction supported without any events. But you can implement this by simple keyboard - incapsulate share logic in keyboard button press event.